# Why is my DI with Dagger2 implementation crashing?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I still can't get my head around how Dagger2 needs to be integrated. I'm coding in Java and most of the tutorials out there are in Kotlin, which I'm not very familiar with.

I have this class that I need to be injected:

```
package org.example.client;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ServerConfiguration {

    private String mServer;

    @Inject
    public ServerConfiguration() {

        this.mServer = "https://api.example.org";
    }

    public String getServer() {

        return mServer;
    }
}
```

And I have this class which requires the above `ServerConfiguration` class:

```
package org.example.client;

import android.util.Log;

public class ApiClient<R extends Request> {

    @Inject
    ServerConfiguration mConfiguration;

    protected ApiClient(Builder<R> builder) {

        if (mConfiguration == null) {

            logd("Injection failed.");
        } else {

            logd("Injection succeeded.");
        }

        logd("Server = " + mConfiguration);
    }

    public void execute() {

        logd("Executing: " + mConfiguration.getServer());
    }

    private static void logd(String m) {

        Log.d("ApiClient", m);
    }

    public static class Builder<R extends Request> {

        public ApiClient<R> build() {

            return new ApiClient<>(builder);
    }
}
```

My expectation is that elsewhere, I can use `new ApiClient.Builder<SomeRequest>().set().build().execute()` and be done with it. Whatever I need to set on a per-request basis will be done through the set() methods of the Builder, and whatever is required on a per-server basis will be done through setters in the ServerConfiguration class. Specifically, I don't need Modules or Components for this basic use-case - that Dagger will notice the @Inject annotation, figure out how to construct the ServerConfiguration object and ensure that is done only once because of the @Singleton. My understanding here seems to be incorrect, because what I get is the log entry "Injection failed." in all cases (and an NPE in execute()). Where am I going wrong?

I have been trying to get Dagger2 going for a while now but failing so far. Is there a good book on the subject?

Comment: Dagger2 is tough to understand but as the time goes, you will understand it. Please share more info about the modules ( Activity module and Application Module)

Comment: Try again by making ```@Inject ServerConfiguration mConfiguration; ``` public as   ```@Inject public ServerConfiguration mConfiguration; ```

Comment: have a look at dagger 2 implementation https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Clean-architecture-android

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the generic nature of `class ApiClient<R extends Request>` was the problem. For each API call I need to subclass this (eg: `class AuthClient extends ApiClient<AuthRequest>` and inject into those subclasses. This actually reduces the utility of Dagger2 somewhat but I intend to persevere.

Answer (score 0):

You are Injecting `ServerConfiguration` in your client but where you are notifiying `Dagger` to inject this dependency, therefore it is not able to instantiate the `ServerConfiguration`.

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. You can notify Dagger and it will do the field injection. For eg:
   `component.inject(<Your current class>)`.
2. You can perform the constructor injection of `ServerConfiguration` object in your API Client constructor. So now whenever Dagger or you are creating the instance of the `API client class`, `ServerConfiguration` instance will be required.

This is the main reason for your API Client to crash.

**Hope it helps.**